# timestamp in drupal views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a field from a custom table which is timestamp. I need to show this timestamp in actual date in drupal vie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Table Wizard module](https://drupal.org/project/tw) can be used to expose custom tables to Views, with the help of the [Schema module](https://drupal.org/project/schema).

Comment: Hi Matt, I've used those already. Actually I am using an INT in DB to store a date in timestamp. Now when I get this field in views through table wizard it gives me in timestamp. I just need to convert it in date when it is shown through views.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to expose this custom table to view. This would require a custom module I believe.

Below is an article that goes over some of what would be needed.

http://www.freshblurbs.com/drupal-expose-custom-field-views2